# Confused about why I'm getting a TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, class

I've looked at similar questions and still have not been able to figure this out. I'm absolutely sure i'm making a very stupid mistake somewhere but I just can't seem to find it.

For this code.

```
class BankAccount:
    def __init__(self, initial_balance):
        self.balance = initial_balance

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.deposit = amount
        self.balance = self.balance + self.deposit

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        self.withdraw = amount 
        self.balance = self.balance - self.withdraw
        self.fee = 5
        self.total_fees = 0

        if self.balance < 0:
            self.balance = self.balance - self.fee
            self.total_fees += self.fee 

    def get_balance(self):
        current_balance = self.balance
        return current_balance

    def get_fees(self):
        return self.total_fees
```

When I run the code everything works fine when I run this

```
my_account = BankAccount(10)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(20)
print my_account.get_balance(), my_account.get_fees()
```

However, if I make an additional call to withdraw

```
my_account = BankAccount(10)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.withdraw(15)
my_account.deposit(20)
print my_account.get_balance(), my_account.get_fees()
```

It throws this error.

> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

I don't understand why it works fine until I make an additional call to withdraw. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `self.deposit = amount`, you overwrite your `deposit` method with the amount.  You do the same in `withdraw` with `self.withdraw = amount`.  You need to give the data attributes a different name from the methods (like call the method `withdraw` but the attribute `withdrawalAmount` or something like that).

Answer (score 4):

When you do this inside the `withdraw` method

```
self.withdraw = amount
```

you replace the it with whatever `amount` is. Next time you call `withdraw`, you get the `amount` object. Which in your case is an `int`.

The same applies to `deposit`:

```
self.deposit = amount
```

Give your data members names that are different to your methods.